# Why can’t I get a red dot instead of spread out light when collimating the primary mirror

Tags: collimation

Using a laser collimator, I have centered the dot for the secondary mirror, but all I see is spread out light when I go to adjust the primary mirror.  Shouldn’t I be able to see a dot, and move that to the center?  Thanks for help.  I am a beginner.  Using a Celestron 130 Star Sense reflector.

Comment: Yes, you should see a dot, so something is wrong.  Your best option is to find a local club that can help.

Comment: I will try to find a local club.  I know there used to be one a few years ago.